# zayit.exe appcrash when trying to open an HttpConnection

Tags: java-me, midp, j2mepolish, java-wireless-toolkit

I am facing a problem while trying to open an HttpConnection in my J2ME app.

I am running the app using the emulator but when it comes to the line of code to open the HttpConnection as:

HttpConnection connection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(URL);

a dialog appears saying that the app has crashed (zayit.exe).

What am I missing to configure?

Comment: what version emulator are you using? have you tested your application with java ME SDK 3?